# MS word macro: how to change highlights form a specific color to another — inside the selected text?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, microsoft-word-2013

I want to change the yellow highlights in the selected text (not in the whole document) to red highlights. This VBA does change the highlighted colors but it does not stop at the selected text (it also changed the highlights bellow the selected text).

```
Sub SwitchHighlightsColor()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveDocument.Range

    With r.Find
        .Highlight = True
        .Forward = True
        Do While .Execute(FindText:="", Forward:=True) = True
            If r.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then   ' Highlight color you want to change
                r.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed          ' the new Highlight color you want to have
                r.Collapse 0
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that the exact code? I thought r.Find would require an argument of what you want to find?

Comment: @Jonno the original code was with  "ActiveDocument.Range" I changed it in my question. The selection.range was my try, but a wrong one. (Thanks: I edited my question)

Comment: The original code us the one in my question (the r.find was without parenthesis). Yes I want all the yellow highlight of my *selection* to change in red.  (The original code: http://www.exp-systems.com/forum_exp/forum_posts.asp?TID=580 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the following alterations:

```
Sub SwitchHighlightsColor()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Application.Selection.Range

    With r.Find
        .Highlight = True

        Do While .Execute(FindText:="") And r.InRange(Application.Selection.Range)
            If r.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then   ' Highlight color you want to change
                r.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed          ' the new Highlight color you want to have
                r.Collapse 0
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

This alternate code works on a per-letter basis, rather than a per-word basis. As such, it should change any letters with highlighting to the correct colour. It will, however, be hard to undo as you need to undo each letter individually instead of all in one go.

```
Sub SwitchHighlightsColorPerLetter()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Application.Selection.Range

    With r.Find
        .Highlight = True

        Do While .Execute(FindText:="") And r.InRange(Application.Selection.Range)
            For Each x In r.Characters
                If x.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then   ' Highlight color you want to change
                    x.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed          ' the new Highlight color you want to have
                    x.Collapse 0
                End If
            Next
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: wonderful! Thank you very much. (There is just a small issue when the yellow highlight is directly preceded or followed by another highlight color —without any space between then—, then the macro doesn't recognized it, and thus doesn't change the second color.).

Comment: @Lisa Not sure if you still needed it, but I added a VBA code that works per-letter instead of per-word, so would work even if two highlight colours are in the same word.

Comment: I'm very touched by that, especially because I already marked it as the best answer (and it was). Now it's not only the best answer, but the kindliest! Thank you so much (And yes I still need it! And by the way the effect is beautiful!)

Comment: @Lisa Not a problem, glad I could help =)